# How To Get A Result URL After Clicking Search On Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, safari

I have an iPad app here. It opens http link using safari within the app.

I use this command to open the http link:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
```

When I for example enter a search string, "cocoa" on let say google.com search box, it returns https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=nUQUU_ebMcqM8Qe-1oDwAw#q=cocoa

How do I grab that result URL above from my iOS app?

Comment: Your app can't get url from Safari browser. You want to use `UIWebView` inside your app for this. Using `UIWebViewDelegate` methods you can get urls loading in the webview.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept your answer. You can earn reputation points and also your answer can help others.

Comment: @Amar I cannot vote for my own answer. :)

Comment: Need to accept the answer. Click on the tick mark which appears under the arrows next to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a UIWebview delegate methods and implemented:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
switch (navigationType) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:");
            strNewURL = [request.URL absoluteString];
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted:");
            strNewURL = [request.URL absoluteString];
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward:");
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload:");
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted:");
            break;
        case 5:
            NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther:");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

If I were to do a search on safari from within my app, it calls this method, `UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted` and I just need to extract the URL using `[request.URL absoluteString]`